# Determining whether an interval (0,1] $\in\mathfrak B(\mathbb R)$ or not.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Determine, with justification, if the interval $(0,1]$ $\in\mathfrak B(\mathbb R)$ or not, given $\mathfrak B(\mathbb R)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$, which contains all the the open sets.

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem. I'd really appreciate any tips on how to prove this or any solutions.

Comment: $(0,1]=(0,2)\setminus(1,3)$.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remember that countable intersections of Borel sets are Borel, and notice we can write $$(0,1]=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (0, 1+\frac{1}{n})$$

Comment: OK but I'm not sure how to get from this to the answer Henning Makholm gave under the question. Would you be able to show me?

Comment: Actually his answer is simpler.  Since the subtraction of 2 Borel sets is Borel, and (0,2) and (1,3) are Borel, then (0,2)-(1,3) is also Borel.  My answer is simply a more general approach by building closed intervals out of open intervals

Comment: In other words, he uses the fact that "set minus" preserves Borel.  I use the fact that "set intersect" preserves Borel